# Python class inheritance dynamic class variable

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

This is what I want to do:

```
class Base:
    _type = None
    name: str = _type.name

class a(Base):
    _type = UnityType

a_instance = a()
a_instance.name  # Expecting UnityType.name to be some string.
```

While trying this, I get `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`. The reason is clear and understandable. But how can I pass the responsibility of implementing a variable class to a subclass?

Comment: I don't understand why you're saying `_type` is a `str` in the first place if you want it to be something that has a `name` attribute...

Comment: Just fixed the typing error. @Samwise. _type is a class.

Comment: You could define `__init__()` and put the name on the instance when the instance is initialized? Although it's not clear what should happen when someone creates `Base()`.

Comment: As long as you don't need `a._type.name` to work ,only `a_instance._type.name`, initialize the attributes in `a`'s `__init__` method. If you need it to work on `a` itself, put it in the metaclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `Base.name` to be a `property`, so that it's evaluated when it's accessed rather than when `Base` is defined:

```
from typing import Optional, Protocol, Type

class Named(Protocol):
    name: str

class Base:
    _type: Optional[Type[Named]] = None

    @classmethod
    @property
    def name(cls) -> str:
        assert cls._type is not None
        return cls._type.name

class UnityType:
    name = "Unity"

class a(Base):
    _type = UnityType

a_instance = a()
print(a_instance.name)  # prints "Unity"
```

I'm assuming from your example that `UnityType` is a type, not an instance, and that you want `Base` to work with either that type or other types with a `name` class attribute, so I defined a `Protocol` that requires that and  used that for the type annotation of `Base` (the above passes mypy without complaint).

Comment: Great answer. You didn't have all the information to give me a specific answer, but you helped me a lot and I solved the problem with your help. Thank you.